# Weird NoMethodError only in PRODUCTION when new User is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, jwt, production-environment

HELP!

I recently added API functionality for User registration and login via API and devise-jwt. When I pushed this onto my heroku production environment now, it suddenly throws a new error when somebody tries to sign up.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `jti' for #<User:0x00007f59d0453ab8>):
app/models/user.rb:33:in `add_jti'
```

Signing up locally on my development environment works without any problems.
Here are other key points:

- logging in works fine for already created users
- Already existing users also have the "jti" attribute and it can be called as a method
- It is possible to create users via terminal commands on the production environement, here it basically does the same thing as in normal registration but for some reason has no problem calling this "jti" method.
- The versions of the gems seems to be the same in both variables.
- debugging in the method that causes the problem shows no problem in development environment

Here is the code for the User model, where the bug is caused...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable

  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, format: { without: /\s/ }

  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy 

  acts_as_voter

  before_create :add_jti
  def add_jti
    self.jti ||= SecureRandom.uuid
  end

end
```

There is also a model for "Api-User", which makes use of the jwt strategies any everything

```
class ApiUser < User
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher
  devise :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: self
  validates :jti, presence: true
  def generate_jwt
    JWT.encode({ id: id,
                exp: 5.days.from_now.to_i },
               Rails.env.devise.jwt.secret_key)
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're using `devise-jwt` with jti, but I don't see any code for it in your model aside from your custom add_jti hook? Isn't your model supposed to have `Include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher` and `:jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: self` ?

Comment: I use that in another model which is an extension of the user model called "api User", I have updated my question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your migrations ran on heroku?  Doesn't happen automatically on deploy unless you automate that.

Comment: Yeah I did that and also repeated it now, that did not seem to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

ALRIGHT I somehow fixed it myself my accident right now, for anybody in the future experiencing something similar to this, just repeat `git push heroku master`, that somehow solved the problem.
Thanks anybody for suggestions tho ^^.